# Blender Pack Islands Issue

Tags: uv-image-editor

I'm attempting to create a UV Atlas using a method I've been learning in Blender. The problem is, when I get to the point of using the Pack Islands function in the UV Editing window, I wind up with most of my UVs being deconstructed and spread out over the entire map... Is there a way in Blender 3.3.1 or later to avoid this - to me - error? An addon, or the like?[image]